# UIView Image - fade from one image to another

Tags: ios, objective-c

I'm trying to fade from one image to another, using a **SINGLE** UIView (**Yes!** have seen Q&As on stackoverflow, that use 2 UIViews - on top of each other).

**I have a current UIView image, would like to fade it out and replace it with another image, and fade the new image in.**

I have tried the following: The fading of the first , alone, works.

Attempt #1)

```
  // Fade original image - image already set in Storyboard
    [UIView beginAnimations:nil context:NULL];
    [UIView setAnimationDuration:5.0];
    [UIView setAnimationDelegate:self];
    [_imgMirror setAlpha:0.0];
    [UIView commitAnimations];


    // Fade in new image
    [_imgMirror setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"NewImage"]];
    [UIView beginAnimations:nil context:NULL];
    [UIView setAnimationDuration:5.0];
    [_imgMirror setAlpha:100.0];
    [UIView commitAnimations];
```

This fades in new image... Old image does not fade. Also tried 'pausing' between the 2 groups of code.

Attempt #2)

```
UIImage * toImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"NewImage"];
[UIView transitionWithView:self.imgMirror
                  duration:0.33f
                   options:UIViewAnimationOptionTransitionCrossDissolve
                animations:^{
                    self.imgMirror.image = toImage;
                } completion:NULL];
```

This shows the new image immediately, never fades or 'CrossDissolves'.

Attempt #3)

```
  // Fade original image - image already set in Storyboard
        [UIView beginAnimations:nil context:NULL];
        [UIView setAnimationDuration:5.0];
        [UIView setAnimationDelegate:self];
        [_imgMirror setAlpha:0.0];
        [UIView commitAnimations];



UIImage * toImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"NewImage"];
    [UIView transitionWithView:self.imgMirror
                      duration:0.33f
                       options:UIViewAnimationOptionTransitionCrossDissolve
                    animations:^{
                        self.imgMirror.image = toImage;
                    } completion:NULL];
```

This has the same result as #2.

Any idea what is wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this. It fades the image out, swaps the image without an animation, then fades in with another animation.

```
CGFloat fadeDuration = 0.5f;
[UIView animateWithDuration:fadeDuration animations:^{
    [_imgMirror setAlpha:0.0];
} completion:^(BOOL finished) {
    UIImage * toImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"NewImage"];
    _imgMirror.image = toImage;
    [UIView animateWithDuration:fadeDuration animations:^{
        [_imgMirror setAlpha:1.0];
    }];
}];
```

Answer (score 1):

You cannot "cross fade" from one UIImage to another by setting the `.image` property of your image view.

You *can* do it with an "intermediary" image view though.

Assuming you have a `UIImageView` connected via `IBOutlet`, and a button connected via IBAction:

```
//
//  CrossFadeViewController.m
//
//  Created by Don Mag on 3/7/18.
//

#import "CrossFadeViewController.h"

@interface CrossFadeViewController ()

@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIImageView *imgMirror;

@end

@implementation CrossFadeViewController

- (IBAction)didTap:(id)sender {

    [self crossFadeTo:@"NewImage"];

}

- (void) crossFadeTo:(NSString *)newImageName {

    UIImageView *toImageView;

    // create a new UIImageView with the new Image
    toImageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:newImageName]];

    // set the new image view's frame to match the existing one
    toImageView.frame = _imgMirror.frame;

    // cross-fade / dissolve from the existing image view to the new one
    [UIView transitionFromView:_imgMirror
                        toView:toImageView
                      duration:0.33
                       options:UIViewAnimationOptionTransitionCrossDissolve
                    completion:^(BOOL finished) {
                        // when animation is finished
                        // remove the "old" image view from its superview
                        [_imgMirror removeFromSuperview];
                        // assign the new image view to the IBOutlet property
                        _imgMirror = toImageView;
                    }];

}

@end
```